# How to draw different Pattern in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to draw the different pattern in the flutter like this [image]

Although this code is javascript is given  in this [link](http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/#double-lines..)

Comment: see `ImageShader` official documentation

Comment: @pskink I tried  ... what value I have to put here `..shader =
          ImageShader(image, TileMode.clamp, TileMode.clamp, Float64List(16))`

Comment: I got it using gradient thanks

Comment: I created Linera gradient and used this as but it still need some improvement 
 `shader = gradient.createShader(myRect)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used ImageShader and used shader property of Paint Function
device transform is used to get the device pixel so that it can render the effect 
This is my paint method look like...

```
 final double devicePixelRatio = ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        final Float64List deviceTransform = new Float64List(16)
          ..[0] = devicePixelRatio
          ..[5] = devicePixelRatio
          ..[10] = 1.0
          ..[15] = 2.0;
        Float64List matrix = new Float64List(16);
        print('matrix is $matrix');
        print('image is coming in paint    $image');
        Paint paint = new Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..shader = ImageShader(
              image, TileMode.repeated, TileMode.repeated, deviceTransform)
          ..strokeWidth = 40.2;
        paths.forEach((path) {
          canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        });
        repaint = false;
      }
```

Comment: what are those magic numbers like `..[0]` `..[5]` `..[10]` `..[15]`? why dont you use `Matrix4` methods to change your `Matrix4`? did you check the official [Matrix4](http://localhost/flutter/doc-0.10.0/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix4-class.html) documentation?

Comment: so did you see `Matrix4#scale()` and/or `Matrix4#scaled()` methods? why dont you use them? isnt it better to use such a method instead of using ..[0] ..[5] ..[10] ..[15] magic numbers?

Comment: I am using them because I want to check for different device and they are working fine for me.