# Dart (Flutter) canvas.drawImageRect: draw circle Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert an image to an Uint8List.

This is my code:

```
  Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromCanvas(int width, int height, urlAsset) async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);

    final ByteData datai = await rootBundle.load(urlAsset);
    var imaged = await loadImage(new Uint8List.view(datai.buffer));
    canvas.drawImageRect(
      imaged,
      Rect.fromLTRB(
          100, 100, imaged.width.toDouble(), imaged.height.toDouble()),
      Rect.fromCircle(center: new Offset(100, 100), radius: 100),
      new Paint(),
    );

    final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(width, height);
    final data = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return data.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

This gives a rectangle Image and not a circle Image .
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: and why would it give a circle image?

Comment: I'm new to flutter.... I thought that because I added, Rect.fromCircle that it would give a circle?

Comment: no, `Rect.fromCircle` still returns ordinary `Rect`(check the sources how it is implemented)  - what you need is `ImageShader`

Comment: Thanks! I red the documentation, is it correct that i need  to add this after the paint: Paint()
        ..shader =
            ImageShader( constructors ),        Which constructors should I use to get the circle?

Comment: there is only one constructor, if you have image for example 100x100, draw a circle with radius 50 and center 50,50 with that paint

Comment: If I use this code: Paint() ..shader = ImageShader( constructors ), it says 4 constructors are required. Do you please have an example code? Thank you very much!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831036/2252830 (i dont know if you can pass a `null` as a last parameter - you have to r\try it by yourself, if not use [identity matrix](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix4/Matrix4.identity.html) and `storage` property)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display the image with a circle crop, you can use [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html). This should apply a circle crop to the image that will be displayed on the Widget.

```dart
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    color: Colors.white,
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: Image.memory(getBytesFromCanvas(width, height, urlAsset)),
    ),
  ),
),
```