# How to get real image size on screen after boxfit on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use the following code to draw an image on the screen. I want to draw an overlay on top of this image. However, when the image height is larger, the boxfit reduces the image width. I cannot calculate the image top and left drawn position when this happens. The image width and height are still equal to screen size, but image width is drawn centered with gaps on both sides, which is clearly less than the screen size.

Is there a way to calculate the accurate size and top, left the position after the image has been bixfited.

```
return Image.memory(
     imageBytes,
     width: reqWidth,
     height: reqHeight,
     filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
     fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
);
```

Comment: if you have to use `Canvas` api for drawing your overlay why not use `Canvas.drawImage` and get rid of `Image.memory`?

Comment: I can but it's not just drawing an image. This image is segmented and puzzle pieces are created out of it. So the precise size of the image is needed in order to draw puzzle pieces. See here for the example.

https://dragosholban.com/2019/02/16/building-a-puzzle-game-using-flutter/.

Comment: so instead of `Canvas.drawImage` use `ImageShader` and `Camvas.drawPath()` - no need for `ClipPath` - do your complete drawing inside `PuzzlePiecePainter`

Comment: thanks, but can't find any example of ImageShader. How do I incorporate that into the sample?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831036/2252830

Comment: Don't see how imageshader helps here. Can you elaborate it bit more please. it should include clippath so user click events impact on the puzzle piece area.

Comment: something like that: https://pastebin.com/raw/RgMBjBSQ

Comment: yup, thanks. I ll try it out. Does it take into account of clip path?
 Also Noticed applyBoxFit method u have used. So trying to use that and improve the existing implementation.

Comment: `"So trying to use that and improve the existing implementation"` - it will not work - that implementation is a workaround - sooner or later you will get into another problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `applyBoxFit(BoxFit.fitHeight, widgetSize, imageSize)`

Where:

- widgetSize - size of rendered Image widget. In your case, it is `Size(reqWidth, reqHeight)`
- imageSize - size of your image asset in pixels. [How to get image size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44683714/11074869)

References:
[applyBoxFit](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/applyBoxFit.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem to you and managed to solve it with a combination of `FittedBox` and `Stack`. Any children of the `Stack` within the `FittedBox` have the same coordinate space:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.network('test.jpg'),
            Positioned(
              top: 100,
              left: 100,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The container widget is now positioned relative to the image *after* the box fit has been applied.